# how to setup laravel 7.2.1 with mongodb

Tags: laravel

how to setup laravel 7.2.1 with mongodb

```
Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.3
    - Conclusion: don't install jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.2
    - Conclusion: don't install jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v7.2.1
    - Installation request for jenssegers/mongodb ^3.6 -> satisfiable by jenssegers/mongodb[v3.6.0, v3.6.1, v3.6.2, v3.6.3].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.2.1
    - jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.0 requires illuminate/events ^5.8|^6.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/events[5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.2, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0].
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.2.1
```

Problem occurs

Comment: He didn't yet updated his package to be compatible with laravel 7

Answer (score 6):

You can install the alpha version which supports Laravel ^7.0

```
 composer require jenssegers/mongodb:4.0.0-alpha.1
```

Answer (score 1):

As per  `jenssegers/laravel-mongodb`  package [official github repository](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) it does not support `Laravel7.x` version.

[image]

Reference:

https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
composer require jenssegers/mongodb:dev-develop
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a version developed by Collaborators on github
you can use it in `laravel 7` .
like this :

```
"jenssegers/mongodb": "^4"
```

then

```
composer update
```

or

```
composer install
```

[laravel-mongodb version 4](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/1974)